# R=X*Y is the relationship. Is predicting R and X and obtain Y same as predicting X and Y to obtain R?

Tags: predictive-models, causality

Of course the numbers will be different, I mean more in terms of relationship. I know that X affect R and Y affects R . X and Y are independent but since R is a product of X and Y , I dont think that I can calculate Y just by dividing R estimate by X estimate ? I dont know why, but it feels like a wrong approach . Can you help me to understand why or why not it is a wrong approach?

Comment: If $R=X \times Y$ is exact and you know any two of them then you can calculate the third using multiplication or division (at least when $R$ is non-zero).  But if you are only estimating two of them then this may not be the best estimate of the third.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I think. How can I answer the question, why estimating Y from estimated of R and X is a bad idea? Is estimating R from estimate of X and Y equally bad idea?

Comment: What are these "estimates" and how are they computed, from what kinds of data?  What might cause an estimate to differ from some "true" value and how would you characterize the possible distribution of such differences?

Comment: lets say R is revenue, X is the number of items sold and Y is the price (time varying) of items sold. Lets say time varying Y is hard to forecast. I have historical Revenue figures, thus i can create an ARIMA model say, for R, and lets say a Random Forest Regression for X. At the end of the day, I want to have both R , X, and Y forecasts. Is it fair to say that Y forecasted via some model is more trustworthy than Y deducted from R forecast/ X forecast?

Answer (score 1):

### The equation states equality, not causality

The equals sign gives you equality, nothing more, nothing less. You have three numbers that are in some relation to one another that's defined by the equation. There is no notion of causality there. In causal models, one typically uses assignment operators like $\leftarrow$ or $:=$ to differentiate between causal definitions and conventional equations. That said, your point is a common question and in fact one of the examples for how humans tend to think causally in Judea Pearl's "Book of Why".